# Como usar lambdas e stream?

Tags: java, expressões-lambda, stream

Eu consigo entender expressões `lambdas` perfeitamente em casos simples como:

```
() -> 42              // Não recebe nada e sempre retorna "42"
x -> x*x              // Recebe algo e retorna seu quadrado
(x,y) -> x + y        // Recebe dois valores e retorna sua soma
```

Mas **nunca** está assim nos códigos e sim de um jeito mais complexo, ilegível para mim. O trecho de código abaixo faz uma busca no *Elastic Search* e a retorna. Após um refactor, é necessário que list seja `BasicDBObject` mas o que faz a próxima linha? Eu sei apenas pelo debug os elementos que são acessados e retornados. O que "significa" este código? Digo, não somente este em específico mas as "sintaxes" de streams?

```
 BasicDBList list = esClient.search("oknok", "base_gerenciada", "{\"size\":9999999,\"query\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"match\":{\"last\":true}},{\"match\":{\"spec_virtual\":\"não\"}},{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"" + search + "* OR spec_veiculo:" + search + "*\",\"default_operator\":\"AND\"}}]}}}");
 return list.parallelStream().map((temp) -> (BasicDBObject) ((BasicDBObject) temp).get("_source")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Debug
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

******Alterando o retorno para `BasicDBObject`, consegui reescrever este trecho:

```
BasicDBObject dbObject = esClient.search("oknok", "base_gerenciada", "{\"size\":9999999,\"query\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"match\":{\"last\":true}},{\"match\":{\"spec_virtual\":\"não\"}},{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"" + search + "* OR spec_veiculo:" + search + "*\",\"default_operator\":\"AND\"}}]}}}");
BasicDBList list = (BasicDBList) ((BasicDBObject) dbObject.get("hits")).get("hits");
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
   myList.add((BasicDBObject) ((BasicDBObject) list.get(i)).get("_source"));
}
return myList;
```

Comment: Esse código é realmente java?

Comment: Java 8, acredito :)

Comment: Sim, isso é Java 8. Que bom que não sou a única que não está familiarizada ainda!

Comment: esse java8 ta ficando complicado :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Segue a visão explicativa da sintaxe com referencias detalhadas em links:

```
BasicDBList list = (... Implementa Collection ...)
```

A [nova interface Collection (java 8)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) traz a [implementação default](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-8-explained-default-methods/) de ambos:

```
default Stream<E> stream() {
default Stream<E> parallelStream() {
```

No seu caso sendo chamado explicitamente pela sua Collection:

> Nota-se que foi usado o **parallelStream**, nesse a própria API decompõe o tratamento do
>   stream paralelizando sua execução de forma transparente.

```
list.parallelStream()
                      .map(...sua funcao...)
```

> o [método map](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/stream/Stream.java#Stream.map%28java.util.function.Function%29) -implementado pela stream- retorna um elemento do stream aplicando a [função](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/function/Function.java#Function) informada, no seu caso:

```
(temp) -> (BasicDBObject) ((BasicDBObject) temp).get("_source")
```

temp é o elemento da stream a ser aplicada a função que é:

- Um cast no elemento **temp**
- Seguido por um **get no LinkedHashMap
  pela chave String**

```
((BasicDBObject) temp) // cast
                      .get("_source") // obtendo Map<String, BasicDBObject>
```

E finalmente o collect, que aplica uma *Mutable Reduction*, agregando os elementos retornados pela função no *container* especificado, no seu caso uma **Collectors.toList()** -implementação de *List*- ou poderia ser também um StringBuilder por exemplo usando **Collectors.joining(", ")**.

```
.collect(Collectors.toList())
```

**Visão geral do fluxo da Stream:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Link do Blog da Oracle com mais detalhes.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html)

Comment: Muito boa a resposta. Streams me parece que necessita de uma boa prática, depois de uns dias lendo sobre e depois reler a sua resposta é o ideal