# Como fazer cópia de um atributo de uma lista em java

Tags: java

Exemplo de cópia:

```
List<MyObject> listaDeObjetos = new ArrayList<>();

List<String> nomes = new ArrayList<>();
for (MyObject obj : listaDeObjetos) {
   nomes.add(obj.getNome());
}
```

Tem algo no java que facilite isso?

Comment: Facilitar em que sentido?

Comment: Não que eu saiba. Se isso for muito constante no seu código, aconselho extrair a lógica para um método (estático ou para uma classe Abstrata) para que possa reutilizar sua lógica.

Comment: Qual a versão do Java? Até o 7, creio que não exista nada para simplificar isso, a forma como você está fazendo me parece ideal. A partir do 8, com o suporte a [lambdas](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269/215), deve existir um meio mais simples e conciso de fazer o que você quer, mas não sei como. Talvez você encontre alguma informação útil na pergunta ["Como usar lambdas e stream?"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70544/215)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No Java 8 é possível fazer isso através do uso de [**streams**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70544/215):

```
List<MyObject> listaDeObjetos = new ArrayList<>();

List<String> nomes = listaDeObjetos.stream().map(MyObject::getNome)
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Não sei qual o tipo exato da lista que esse `Collectors.toList()` está retornando. Se você realmente precisar que seja um `ArrayList`, pode substitui-lo pelo `toCollection`:

```
                     .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Por fim, se sua lista for muito grande *talvez* compense substituir o `stream()` por `parallelStream()`, de modo que o Java possa distribuir o processamento por múltiplos núcleos (nesse caso simples é provável que não compense).

Não conheço nada no Java 7 ou anterior que possa facilitar essa tarefa, o mais simples é fazer um loop mesmo, tal como você já está fazendo. A propósito, no quesito "performance" eu acredito (mas não testei) que seu loop seja mais rápido que o uso das streams, e nesse caso simples um é tão conciso quanto o outro.